# How to get ETH or BSC unverified contract ABI

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, bep20

I want to find a deployed but not verified contract ABI~ There is api to find verified contract ABI but not support the unverified.Is there any ways to find a deployed but not verified contract ABI~ Like this contract 0x9447e3eD2A23572F7Be359216321f7e67B364BaC on BSC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through mined blocks and their transactions, and search for transaction receipts without `to` value and with `contractAddress` value.

```
for (let blockNumber = 13188112; blockNumber < 13188113; blockNumber++) {
    const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(blockNumber);
    for (let txHash of block.transactions) {
        const receipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash);
        if (receipt.to === null && receipt.contractAddress !== undefined) {
            // found a contract-creating transaction
            console.log(receipt.contractAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

You can expand on this code to query the BSCScan API to find out if the contract address is verified on their site or not.